# How to implement a graph convolution layer that uses different weight matrices for the self-node?

Tags: graph, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

How can I implement a graph convolution layer that uses different weight matrices for the self-node?

I want to implement the attached equation below. Currently, I'm using the implementation from [here](https://github.com/tkipf/pygcn/blob/master/pygcn/layers.py). But it doesn't use different weight matrices for the self-node.

A shape of my input tensor is `[256,17,2]` and the shape of my adjacency matrix tensor is `[17,17]`.

[image]
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei4mB.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can use an identity `matrix E` for the self node and use `1-E` for the neighbour nodes. Like in the below,

```
E = torch.eye(adjacentMatrix.size(0), dtype=torch.float)

output = torch.matmul(adjacentMatrix* E, (torch.matmul(input,Q))) + torch.matmul(adjacentMatrix * (1 - E), (torch.matmul(input,W)))
```

`Q` and `W` are learnable here